# Can I detect if a function is being recursively called (i.e., reentrant) in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I provide a function, such as `runByChannel`, where I intend to send a lambda to a channel for execution, and then use a CompletableDeferred to receive the result. One scenario I need to avoid is calling runByChannel again within the lambda executed by runByChannel. This could lead to a deadlock.

In a non-coroutine environment, you can use a ThreadLocal variable to design a flag indicating whether the function has already entered in the current thread. You would check this flag every time you enter. However, in a coroutine environment, thread scheduling is not fixed, so I think ThreadLocal is not useful. Is there a better way? Note, I cannot design a parameter chain to express the number of entries because runByChannel will call other functions in the middle, and this parameter cannot be passed down continuously.

Comment: I'm confused by your question where you assert that reentrant functions are recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  `ThreadLocal` is pretty much never useful for coroutines, but the `CoroutineContext` does the job; it is automatically passed downward recursively through coroutines calls and launches.

```
object Recursive: CoroutineContext.Element, CoroutineContext.Key<Recursive> {
  override val key: CoroutineContext.Key<Recursive> get() = this
}

suspend fun cantCallMeRecursively(lambda: suspend () -> Unit) {
  require(currentCoroutineContext()[Recursive] == null) { "recursively called" }
  withContext(Recursive) { lambda() }
}
```